# Execute "ng-repeat" asynchronously

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use `$("#div1").load("aa.html")` to load "aa.html" into a webpage,there is a "ng-repeat" directive in "aa.html",after loading it,"ng-repeat" wasn't executed by angularjs,it's directly appeared in DOM,but if i directly place "aa.html" content inside $("#div1"),it can be executed by angularjs. How can I let angularjs execute this "ng-repeat" after jquery loading this page?

Comment: I cant't use ng-include because it needs logic to determine whether to load it or not.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to register the contorller

```
function registerController(moduleName, controllerName, template, container) {
// Load html file with content that uses Ctrl controller
//$(template).appendTo(container);
// Here I cannot get the controller function directly so I
// need to loop through the module's _invokeQueue to get it
var queue = angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue;
for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    var call = queue[i];
    if (call[0] == "$controllerProvider" &&
        call[1] == "register" &&
        call[2][0] == controllerName) {
        controllerProvider.register(controllerName, call[2][1]);
    }
}

angular.injector(['ng', moduleName]).invoke(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    $compile($("#" + template))($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

}

after that in you jquery success

registerController('appname', 'controller', "temolatename")

```
angular.element("element").scope().run();
    angular.element("element").scope().$apply();
```